# Online boarding passes for Star Alliance connecting flights

Tags: online-resources, check-in, connecting-flights, lufthansa, air-canada

I booked a trip from Canada to India. I started on Air Canada and transferred to Lufthansa. A day before I left I selected my seats, checked in online and obtained my boarding passes, all through Air Canada's online check-in UI.

However, leaving India, starting on Lufthansa and transferring to Air Canada, I can check in on Lufthansa but I am unable to check in on Air Canada through Lufthansa's UI.

Is something wrong with my trip? Or does Lufthansa simply not support it?

Comment: Try again right before your flight leaves. If you go through the online checkin again, it might be near enough for the connection, and give you both boarding passes the second time.

Comment: You can also ask the Lufthansa agent when you get to the airport in India. They can often get you a boarding pass for a connecting flight even if online check-in cannot, as there are sometimes small quirks they need to take care of that the online system doesn't handle (e.g. accept a five-minute schedule change or note that you've been selected for extra security screening).

Answer (score 1):

Probably everything is fine.  You can try to check in on AC's website, there are cases where the checkin for each flight has to be done with the operating carrier. (I'm not sure if this works with Lufthansa's Amadeus code -- I believe AC has their own codes -- but you should be able to either find this in the booking confirmation or on checkmytrip.com. [EDIT: Since you checked in on AC for the outgoing flight, this would be the same code.])  It might be that this is only possible XX hours prior to the departure of the AC fight.

Another option is that AC wants to do some document check before handing you your boarding pass.  In either case, I wouldn't be too concerned (as long as you have all required documents/eTA/...)

Comment: I will try it and let you know

Comment: @Lordbalmon Good!  I tried to find some old boardingpass/trip where I had a LH/AC combination but I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

Given the flight time from India to Germany, this is probably a timing issue: the check in is not open for the AC flight at the time when you check in the LH flight.

I can guarantee that LH supports (some) interline check in with AC: I connected to AC in FRA from a European LH flight last month and had no problem with LH checking me in the AC flight and producing (electronic) boarding passes for all my flights, including AC flights.  Of course the LH check in was much closer to the time of departure of my later connecting AC flight.

I’ve had some issues when the connecting flight is on another day as the departing flight (overnight stay on a single reservation), although travelling to Europe and connecting on the next day after the overnight flight has never been an issue.

Comment: This is well possible - even though it's often possible to checkin for connecting flights well before the typical <24h deadline.

Comment: @npl it is true that, if you stay with the same operating carrier, check-in for your first flight usually gives you access to all remaining flights of the itinerary, even if those are well before the opening of the check-in window for later flights.  However, the process is often less smooth when different legs are flown on different carriers.  It’s usually IT issues between the carriers.

Comment: I think there are two different "checkin times": First, there is a time when the flight is available (internally) for checkin, and second, there is a time when you can access this directly through online checkin.  The former is often up to 2 days before departure, in my experience - and it is often possible to checkin for such connecting flights.

Answer (score 0):

There are some inconsistencies with the Air Canada checkin system. Just last year I booked via Air Canada a trip of 21 flights, made of 9 non-stop and 6 pairs of connecting flights, so this happened sometimes that I could not check in through those that were connecting flights but everything was OK.

First, as you did try the AC site. When you booked through them, that is the site that is *most likely* to work. Be careful though because they sometimes give you more than one Reference Number (for my 21 flight trip, I had 3), so you have to use the right one at the right time. All numbers were listed on the booking confirmation.

Checkin opens about 23 hours ahead of a flight. When you have a very long flight followed by another, it is possible the next one is still more than 23 hours away, so checkin will not be available. When you have a short and a long then, you may be able to check in one way but not the other because of this.

Sometimes they just can't do it. Although this did not apply to Lufthansa on any on my segments, one AC followed by 2 GOL domestic connections forced me to check in manually at the counter in Brazil.

You mention seat selection which was even spottier throughout my itinerary. I found that doing the selection via TAP Portugal was more success than others, even for non TAP flights (at least for those corresponding the the right reference number). Also they do let you select seats that got ignored by the next airline which happened when I connected from TAP to Thai Airways. This is compounded if you have airline status as some non-AC flight could see my level - and provide the privileges that come with it - but some did not.